# Improper Integral $\int_0^\infty\tan\left(\frac x{\sqrt{x^3+x^2}}\right)\frac{\ln(1+\sqrt x)}xdx$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, improper-integrals, closed-form

This integral is from  [integral](http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com/topic785.html)

Find 
$$\int_0^\infty\tan\left(\frac x{\sqrt{x^3+x^2}}\right)\frac{\ln(1+\sqrt x)}xdx$$

I have get
$$\int_0^\infty\tan\left(\frac x{\sqrt{x^3+x^2}}\right)\frac{\ln(1+\sqrt x)}xdx=\int_0^{\infty}\tan\left(\frac1{\sqrt{x+1}}\right)\frac{\ln(1+\sqrt x)}{x}dx$$
Let$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}}=t$$
that
$$I=\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{\tan{t}\ln{\left(1+\sqrt{\frac{1}{t^2}-1}\right)}}{t-t^3}dt$$
This integral is have  closed form ?

Comment: I have to wonder whether this even exists... won't it oscillate too much as you approach zero?

Comment: Why is this interesting ? (It's possible to construct infinite complicate integrals.) Something special like e.g. with http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/520657/a-conjectured-closed-form-of-int-0-infty-fracx-1-sqrt2x-1-ln-left2x?rq=1 ?

Comment: @user90369,the same as fell

Comment: what does WolframAlpha mean?

Comment: Based on past experience with log integrals, I believe that the integral has a better chance of possessing a closed form if $tan$ were replaced with $tan^{-1}$.